# Comparing user input string to string read from text file

Tags: java, string, input, compare

I'm currently writing this program that I require to read info from a text file and to then compare the info read to a user input and output a message saying if it was a match or not.

Currently have this. The program is sucessfully reading the data specified but I can't seem to compare the strings correctly at the end and print a result.

Code is below any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;      // Required for the scanner
import java.io.File;               // Needed for File and IOException 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; //Required for exception throw

// add more imports as needed

/**
 * A starter to the country data problem.
 * 
 * @author phi 
 * @version starter
 */
public class Capitals
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException // Throws Clause Added
    {
        // ask the user for the search string
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter part of the country name: ");
        String searchString = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();

        // open the data file
        File file = new File("CountryData.csv");

        // create a scanner from the file
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (file);

        // set up the scanner to use "," as the delimiter
        inputFile.useDelimiter("[\\r,]");

        // While there is another line to read.
        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            // read the 3 parts of the line
            String country = inputFile.next(); //Read country
            String capital = inputFile.next(); //Read capital
            String population = inputFile.next(); //Read Population

            //Check if user input is a match and if true print out info.
            if(searchString.equals(country))
            {
                System.out.println("Yay!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fail!");
            }
        }

        // be polite and close the file
        inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try reading the input from a textField in an user interface(visible window) where the user puts the country and getting that as raw input shortens the code.(Only if you have a visible window on screen)

I don't have that good experience with scanners, because they tend to crash my applications when I use them. But my code for the same test does only include a scanner for the file which does not crash my application and looks like following:

```
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(file));

    inputFile.useDelimiter("[\\r,]");
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        String unknown = inputFile.next();
        if (search.equals(unknown)) {
            System.out.println("Yay!");
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();
```

I think the easiest way to compare string against a file is to add a visible window where the user types the country, and reading the input to a string with `String str = textField.getText();`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your comparison is failing due to case-sensitivity.

Should your string comparison not be CASE-INSENSITIVE?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible issues here. First, you're converting the `searchString` to lower case. Are the data in the CSV also lower case? If not, try using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead. Also, it seems to me like you should be able to match parts of the country name. In that case, `equals` (or `equalsIgnoreCase`) would only work if the user inputs the complete country name. If you want to be able to match only a part, use `contains` instead.